# Laravel api request from mobile app receives missing token error page (419)

Tags: angular, laravel, vue.js, ionic-framework

Working on a small ionic framework application with laravel backend.

Request from postman or browser works fine, but builds from Android's getting 419 token mismatch error with same endpoints.

Request Data from Android (error 419):

```
Headers Accept application/json
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
Accept-Language en-AU,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8
Authorization   
[Filtered]
Content-Length 25
Content-Type    application/json
Host    app.example.com
Origin  http://localhost
Referer http://localhost/
Sec-Fetch-Dest  empty
Sec-Fetch-Mode  cors
Sec-Fetch-Site  cross-site
User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 11; SM-A515F Build/RP1A.200720.012; wv) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/93.0.4577.62 Mobile Safari/537.36
X-Requested-With io.ionic.starter
```

Request Data from postman (works fine):

```
Headers Accept */*
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate, br
Connection  keep-alive
Content-Length  0
Content-Type    
Host    app.example.com 
Postman-Token   814dd8ac-e4b3-dfg45-9f87-1649sdfdsfsd0eae
User-Agent  PostmanRuntime/7.28.4
```

Not sure if this is because of CORS or something else. Any idea?
Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Laravel uses csrf tokens on its post requests. You can disable this on routes:
in file app/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken

```
protected $except = [
 'webhook/*'
];
```

(change the route to the routes you want to exclude)

Comment: Is that means all my api POST request needed to be added in exception? not sure why it would work from Postman.. Thanks.

Comment: You can use a wildcard like in the example using `*`. I doubt that a POST request works from Postman or the browser. that would give a 419 error too